# Accessing a reference array with multiple arguments?

Tags: c++

This is a simple tic-tac-toe game as I'm sure you've seen, the code is incomplete. I don't need somebody to look over all of it, just how to format the 2-D character array before '.empty' so that I know how to access it as a reference. If you can take a look at inside the "int get_row()", that'd be great.

I've already tried everything that my textbook and C++ tutorials tell me, and I"m pretty sure none of them have 2-D arrays as part of the exercises. I mean, I can't find it, if you can send a link that'd be nice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;


char board[3][3];


void print_board(char board[3][3])
{
    cout << "   0   1   2 " << endl;
    cout << "0  " << board[0][0] << " | " << board[0][1] << " | " << board[0][2] << " " << endl;
    cout << "  -----------" << endl;
    cout << "1  " << board[1][0] << " | " << board[1][1] << " | " << board[1][2] << " " << endl;
    cout << "  -----------" << endl;
    cout << "2  " << board[2][0] << " | " << board[2][1] << " | " << board[2][2] << " " << endl;
}
void clear_board(char board[][3])
{



}

int get_row(char board[][3], char player)
{
    int row;
    cout << "Please enter the row move for player " << player << endl;
    cin >> row;
    if (board.empty())
        return row;
}

int get_column(char board[][3], char player)
{
        int column;
        cout << "Please enter the column move for player " << player << endl;
        cin >> column;

        return column;
}

bool check_win(char board[][3], char player)
{
    return true;
}

bool board_full(char board[][3])
{
    return true;
}

bool square_occupied(char board[][3],int row,int column)
{
    return true;
}
void get_move(char board[3][3], char player)
{
    do
    {
        do {
            int row, column;
            get_row(board, player);


            get_column(board, player);

            square_occupied(board, row, column);
        } while (square_occupied);
        board_full(board);
    } while (!board_full);

}

int main()
{
    string play_again = "Y", answer;
    int row, column;
    char player = 'X';

    cout << "Welcome to tic-tac-toe!" << endl;
    cout << "Please, use the coordinates for rows and columns to record moves." << endl;
    do {
        do {
            print_board(board);
            board_full(board);


            get_move(board, player);

            check_win(board, player);
            if (player == 'X')
            {
                player = 'O';
            }
            else
            {
                player = 'X';
            }

        } while (!check_win);
        cout << "Would you like to play again? (Y/N)";
        cin >> answer;
    }while (answer == play_again);



    return 0;
}
```

I just want to be able to check if the array container at [row] is going to be empty or not. I really just can't use reference arrays, that's all.

Comment: I mean if it's too hard for you all it's too hard I guess.

Comment: Dude I provided an answer for the question

Comment: I appreciate it for the elaboration, but for the confines of what I'm doing classes are a no-go zone for me at the moment. But thank you for your consideration regardless.

Comment: So are you asking how to pass a reference to a c-array to a function, or...?

Comment: I just wanted to know how to use member functions with a c-array if possible at all. The assignment requires me to use the above and nothing else. I'm just having a hard time manipulating the array outside of the main function whatsoever.

Comment: Use global functions that take the array by reference

Comment: Well, I figured it out through your correspondence. It wasn't taking the array as a reference in the function, I just didn't know the limits of C-arrays if I'm being for real. But thank you for leading me down the thought train to the right station.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a C-array, it's never empty (and also it doesn`t have a`empty` member function).

```
char board[3][3]; //Never empty - always has 9 values
```

Of course, a Tic Tac Toe board can be empty. The array representing the board isn't empty, but the values in the array are probably set to either `0` or some other value that indicates that they're empty.

We can write a small class to represent the board, and give it a `empty` function:

```
struct Board {
    char board[3][3];

    Board() : board() {}
    bool empty() const {
        char* data = &board[0][0];
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if(data[i] != 0) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    bool rowEmpty(int row) const {
        return board[row][0] == 0 && board[row][1] == 0 && board[row][2] == 0;
    }
    bool colEmpty(int col) const {
        return board[0][col] == 0 && board[1][col] == 0 && board[2][col] == 0;
    }
    void putX(int row, int col) {
        board[row][col] = 'X';
    }
    void putO(int row, int col) {
        board[row][col] = 'O';
    }
    // This function returns a reference so you can modify it if you want
    char& getSquare(int row, int col) {
        return board[row][col]; 
    }
};
```

By creating a class to represent the board, you can add whatever functionality and member functions you want!